# Lucene Queries and the AND logical operator

Tags: lucene

I need to AND two NumericRangeQueries and a term query in Lucene .Net version 3.  I know I can use the Combine method for ORs but have not been able to figure out how to do ANDs with queries.  Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `BooleanQuery` and add both queries with `Occur.MUST`. see http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d8/d7c/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_boolean_query.html